# Question about wether ghusl is valid

Tags: ghusl, mistake

My question is that I performed ghusl, but a few hours later I spotted a small peice of something under my nail, I did not know of this while performing ghusl, and I feel like that tuing under my nail stopped water from going there. and I and doubting whether I should do ghusl again, or if it is valid.

Comment: Please tell us why you think it  shouldn't be valid?

Answer (score 0):

Salam, I believe this may be overlooked as you did not see it during ghusl. These may also be the thoughts of waswas so it is best to avoid these doubts.

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/265777

This link may be better suited for your question so I think it would be better to read this rather than listening to anything else beforehand, I hope I have helped.